# A quotient map $X\to X/A$ that is not a Serre fibration

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

What is an example of a CW-pair $(X,A)$ such that the quotient map $X\to X/A$, i.e. the map obtained from the pushout
\begin{eqnarray}
A &\to& X\\
\downarrow &&\downarrow\\
* &\to& X/A
\end{eqnarray}
is not a Serre fibration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Serre fibration with a path connected base has the property that all of its fibers are homotopy equivalent, and this is almost never true of a quotient map $X \to X/A$; the fiber over the basepoint is $A$ but the fiber over any other point is a point. So take, for example, $X = S^2, A = S^1$, with the map $S^1 \to S^2$ being given by some great circle.